# Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi’s yahrtzeit

Tags: sources-mekorot, mishna, yahrtzeit

I’ve seen in various calendars that 15 Kislev is the yahrtzeit of Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi. Does anyone have a source for this?

Comment: Interesting question. So far the oldest source I could find for this is from 1929, in Rabbi Reuven Margolioth's הלולא דצדיקיא, but he mentions it as a well-known fact, so clearly there's a much older source out there.

Comment: Interestingly the custom of the Chevra Kadisha in many of the communities of Lita was to hold their annual fast on 15th Kislev. I believe Chabad still practices this way.

Comment: Other communities [hold it on Adar 7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3231111/jewish/7-Adar-From-Fasting-to-Feasting.htm) @JoelK (which is Moshe Rabbeinu's Yahrzeit, so might be related). [This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2979/israelstudies.20.1.1) seems like it might be a plausible place to look, if anyone has access?

Comment: @RabbiKaii The article you linked to does not provide a source, although it does mention the date as 15 Kislev. It should be noted that Rebbi’s grave is at the necropolis in Beit Shearim, not in Tzippori, as evidenced by the gemara and midrash.